# Editing the ControlTemplate at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, timeline

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <blendables:TimelinePanel IsItemsHost="True" 
            UnitSize="{StaticResource unitSize}" 
            UnitTimeSpan="1"
            BeginDate="1/1/2009"
            EndDate="12/31/2009" 
            />
     </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

What is the best way of being able to change BeginDate and EndDate at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data binding to change them dynamically.

Comment: How do I bind to a property or instance object in the window?